# Open PDF file from UICOLLECTIONViEW selected index objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, uicollectionview, pdf-reader

I am making **PDF** reader application. The **PDF** cover images shown in `collectionviewCell`. I need to open **PDF** with respect to `collectionviewCell`'s index. So please guide how to do this.Cover images of pdf file are shown in collectionview cell.I just want when user tap on any cover the pdf file of that cover is open.i have index of that specific cell.but could not know how to make pdf viewer on user's tap and pass index of collectionviewcell.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 
    NSInteger index = (indexPath.section*2)+indexPath.row; 
    get_index=index; 
    [_previewCoverImage setImage:_objects[indexPath.row]]; 
    [collectionView reloadData]; 
    NSLog(@"this is value %ld",get_index); 
    if (get_index==0) { 

    } 
}
```

Comment: Did you implement `collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` at least? What's your real issue? What's your code?

Comment: In which form you have `PDF`s in `Data` or `URL`.. If `URL` these are local or coming from server? Add more detail to your question and try once yourself to do so.. If still facing any specific issue then ask your question for that problem.

Comment: @Larme yes i have implemented this method.Cover images of pdf file are shown in collectionview cell.I just want when user tap on any cover the pdf file of that cover is open.i have index of that specific cell.but could not know how to make pdf viewer on user's tap and pass index of collectionviewcell.

Comment: @TheTiger for the time being i have PDFs local folder for testing but after completion PDFs will come from url.

Comment: Show your code of `collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` ?

Comment: @TheTiger her is my code - (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSInteger index = (indexPath.section*2)+indexPath.row;
    get_index=index;
    [_previewCoverImage setImage:_objects[indexPath.row]];
    [collectionView reloadData];
    NSLog(@"this is value %ld",get_index);
    if (get_index==0) {
        
    }
}

Comment: @Umar Add this in your question.

Comment: @Umar if you want open pdf file onclick on UICollectionView Cell then first you have pdf file url in your array which is load on UICollectionView Cell. then you will pick url on didSelectItemAt action which load on either browser of your phone or pdf reader app.

Answer (score -1):

```
strFileUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@“%@“,[[YourArray objectAtIndex:indexpath.row] valueForKey:@“url”]];
```

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:strFileUrl];

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url])
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
}
```

Above code - url open in webbrowser.

make sure replace YourArray by your arrayname and "url" by your parameter in your array. you must have pdffile url on your array.

Comment: Thanks for your help.which array replace with YourArray.also please share me the code how i can make url?

Comment: actually for the first time i have to make pdf reader app.I have no idea ho to make this.Thats why i am asking for detail

Comment: @Umar parameter "Url" which load from webservice or may be static file path of your pdf file.

Comment: Thanks for your kind help